# Pretty print expression as entered

Tags: sympy

I would like to pretty print an expression to double check that it's what I want, without any manipulations or simplifications. Here's a simple example:

```
from sympy import *
import abc
init_session()

sigma_1, sigma_0, mu_1, mu_0,x = symbols("sigma_1 sigma_0 mu_1 mu_0 x")
diff = log(1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma_1**2)) * exp(-(x-mu_1)**2/(2*sigma_1**2))) - log(1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma_0**2)) * exp(-(x-mu_0)**2/(2*sigma_0**2)))
diff
```

[image]

This has manipulated the expression a bit, but I'd like to see it pretty printed just in the order I entered it, so I can check it easily against the formulas I've got written down.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid some simplifications by using

```
sympify("log(1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma_1**2)) * exp(-(x-mu_1)**2/(2*sigma_1**2))) - log(1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma_0**2)) * exp(-(x-mu_0)**2/(2*sigma_0**2)))", evaluate=False)
```

However, some simplifications can't be avoided. For example, there's no way to keep terms in the same order, and some expressions, like `1/x` and `x**-1` are internally represented in the same way. With that being said, there are definitely places where `sympify(evaluate=False)` could be improved.